# Rewriting URLs to Be Routed through index.php

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What would be the best way to rewrite URLs like **http://www.example.com/page** to **http://www.example.com/?pg=page**?  When I do it, it works but all the references within the page like JavaScript and CSS get fudged.  Please help.

Comment: Do you want to redirect the first to the second, or merely make the first display the contents as the second (to hide the ugly urls)?

Comment: Gabriel, I've just retagged adding mod_rewrite and `.htaccess` because those are the solution sets that you might use.  I have seen a few dozen variants on your Q in the last week or so.  Why not have a browse of the recent `.htaccess` Qs and adopt one of these?  Have a look at the [Apache rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) and especially use of the `!-f` and `!-d` flags

Comment: Fudged = they were not getting included.  I think the base href mentioned below is a solid backup solution while I have improved the Rewrite code.  I want it so if a person visits **http://www.example.com/page** they're actually visiting **http://www.example.com/?pg=page**.

Comment: You should check out CodeIgniter, it'll help you with your URL routing and is a great, lightweight PHP framework.

Comment: If there is a specific problem with your `.htaccess`, we'll need to see the contents of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ ?pg=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing anyway.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

When using mod rewritten URLs, `<base>` hrefs become very useful! e.g.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <base href="//www.example.com/" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
  ...
```

That source will properly serve the js from `www.example.com/js/script.js` not matter what the URL is.